# antlr listener... which production?

Tags: listener, antlr

Consider:

```
my_rule: a_thing 'as' zoot
       | a_different_thing 'as' blurfl zoot
;
```

In my listener, how do I distinguish the particular production that was matched?  Am I reduced to checking for the presence of **blurfl**, or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Label the alternatives](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels) like this:

```
grammar T;

my_rule
 : a_thing 'as' zoot                  #AltWithoutBlurfl
 | a_different_thing 'as' blurfl zoot #AltWithBlurfl
 ;

...
```

That way, your listener will contain methods like these:

```java
public interface TListener extends ParseTreeListener {

    void enterAltWithoutBlurfl(TParser.AltWithoutBlurflContext ctx);
    void exitAltWithoutBlurfl(TParser.AltWithoutBlurflContext ctx);
    
    void enterAltWithBlurfl(TParser.AltWithBlurflContext ctx);
    void exitAltWithBlurfl(TParser.AltWithBlurflContext ctx);

    ...
}
```

Note that there is no more `enterMy_rule` and `exitMy_rule` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Labels are one solution, but I consider testing for a specific matched element not less elegant and it requires no change to the grammar. Keep also in mind that when you label one alternative in a rule, you have to label all alts. Additionally, having two different functions may lead to code duplication instead of just checking for `blurfl` or any other unique child (e.g. `a_thing`) and otherwise follow the same code path.

Comment: It burns my soul for the parser to find the right production, and then I have to write conditional logic to to take action.